# Pay Rate Calculator

Tags: php, forms, get

I've looked online but all the $_POST and $_GET examples are for text not numbers.
This is not connecting to a database. It doesn't need form validation. It's just a single page project running locally on my system. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

The goal is to have an input where you can put in your hourly pay. For example 15.
Then when you press submit it posts back to the same page with a nice list of how much you make daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<p>Input your Hourly Pay</p>
<form method="GET" action="" >
<input name="num1" type="text" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php

if ($_GET['num1']) {
    $rate = $_GET['num1'];
    return $rate;
}    

$result_day= $rate * 8;
$result_week = $rate * 8 * 5;
$result_month = $rate * 8 * 5  * 4;
$result_year = $rate * 8 * 5  * 4  * 12;

echo "Rate: " . $rate . "<br>";
echo "Daily: " . $result_day . "<br>";
echo "Weekly: " . $result_week . "<br>";
echo "Monthly: " . $result_month . "<br>";
echo "Yearly: " . $result_year . "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: You just need one page that says "not enough for working here" - No script involved!

Comment: You can do this with Javascript. You do not even need the submit button. You can even add the functionality of being able to enter Rate, Dailt, Weekly, ... values and the rest get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I did some correction, but the calculation is still your original:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['num1'])) {
    $rate = $_GET['num1'];   

$result_day= $rate * 8;
$result_week = $result_day * 5;
$result_month = $result_week  * 4;
$result_year = $result_month  * 12;

echo "Rate: " . $rate . "<br>";
echo "Daily: " . $result_day . "<br>";
echo "Weekly: " . $result_week . "<br>";
echo "Monthly: " . $result_month . "<br>";
echo "Yearly: " . $result_year . "<br>";

}else{
 echo  "Please enter your rate!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event with Javascript on any of the fields. You can then use Javascript to calculate the rest of the values and update those fields.

No PHP required. No time lag with a new page required. Users will love it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would try to rewrite this project using JavaScript if I knew it better. At the moment I'm studying PHP and thought this would be a simple project. After PHP I'll dig into JS and jQuery.